# Docker installation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, docker

I'm following the official [Docker installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-docker-engine) to install docker on Ubuntu Focla (20.04).

When I get to

> sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  docker-ce-cli:amd64 

E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate 
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli 
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io' 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
```

I am a novice Linux user and I appreciate any help on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @user535733 done, please check out the updated code.

Comment: @N0rbert thank it seemed to work by only using docker.io in the install code. Thank you. it is amazing that the official docker installation guide for ubuntu is not working!

Comment: Official guide is working. I have just tested it in fresh 20.04 LTS VM. You are probably doing something wrong.